# Overriding Liferay Startup Events

Tags: events, liferay, startup

I have a question with respect to Liferay Startup Events.

In Liferay documentation it is given:

> #### Startup Events
>
> Input a list of comma delimited class names that extend `com.liferay.portal.struts.SimpleAction`. These classes will run at the specified event.

Could anybody please tell me what is the difference between `global.startup.events` and `application.startup.events` and could any body tell me in what case do we need to override them?

And should both these start up events extend `com.liferay.portal.struts.SimpleAction`?? and I couldn't find anything inside the `SimpleAction` except this:

```
public abstract class SimpleAction {

    public abstract void run(String[] ids) throws ActionException;

    }
}
```

I also wanted to know this class contains nothing, how does Liferay knows what XML files to read and process?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

`global.startup.events` - run once for global server

`application.startup.events` - run for every portal instance at startup. If you have one  portal instance at your server (normal case) - here is no difference between this properties. I use `application.startup.events`.

Extend the `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.SimpleAction` class and impliment `run`-methode, that will call by liferay startup. For this purpose create a hook plugin and register in liferay-hook.xml the property file, e.g.:

```
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal-myext.properties</portal-properties>
</hook>
```

Create `portal-myext.properties` in classpath and set your startup action:

```
application.startup.events=com.my.actions.MyStartupAction
```

The action `MyStartupAction` must be in the same classpath, hence same hook-plugin.

Comment: @user1253847 then why don't you accept this as an answer? Thanks